# Check if my data are linearly separable

Tags: machine-learning, classification, svm

This post is followed by the post below:

https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/70395/what-is-the-effect-of-hidden-layer-size

I would like to find out whether my data is linearly separable or not. Following the comment I received in the post linked above, I decided to run a hard-SVM on my data to see the classification results.

My input data, X is a matrix of (10000, 128) and the output/target/classes are (10000, 10). I have 10 classes ranges from 1 to 10.

using following code, I tried LogisticRegression(), svm.LinearSVC(C=1, loss='hinge'), and svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C=1):

```
dataframe = read_csv('data.txt')
array = dataframe.values

X = array[:, 0:128]
y = array[:,-1]

plt.hist(y, bins='auto')  # plt.hist passes it's arguments to np.histogram
plt.title("Histogram with 'auto' bins")
plt.show()

models = []
models.append(('LR', LogisticRegression() ))
models.append(('LSVM', svm.LinearSVC(C=1, loss='hinge') ))
models.append(('LSVM2', svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C=1) ))

results=[]
names=[]
scoring = 'accuracy'
for name, model in models:
    kfold = KFold(n_splits=10, random_state=7)
    cv_results = cross_val_score(model, X, y, cv=kfold, scoring=scoring)
    results.append(cv_results)
    names.append(name)
    msg = "%s: %f (%f)" % (name, cv_results.mean(), cv_results.std())
    print(msg)
```

and here are the results:

```
LR: 0.613360 (0.019632)
LSVM: 0.307829 (0.020123)
LSVM2: 1.000000 (0.000000)
```

I have 2 questions:

(1) is my data linearly separable?

(2) is the results of LSVM2 strange? 
for this I further used

```
models.append(('RBFSVM', svm.SVC(kernel='rbf', gamma=0.7, C=1) ))
models.append(('POLYSVM', svm.SVC(kernel='poly', degree=3, C=1) ))
```

and received the following:

```
RBFSVM: 0.797680(.015187)
POLYSVM: 0.100011(0.008113)
```

can you please help me get more intuition?

Thanks,

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

General note - concept of linear separability applies to **binary datasets**, not 10-classes. If you have more than 2 classes there is no such thing as linear separability, since you can define it in many ways. For the sake of the rest of the answer I will assume that we are talking about  "pairwise linearly separable", meaning that if you choose any two classes they can be linearly separated from each other (note that this is a different thing from having one-vs-all linear separability, as there are datasets which are one-vs-one linearly separable and are not one-vs-all linearly separable).

First of all to check if data is linearly separable **do not** use cross validation. Just fit your model to entire data and check the error, there is no need for train/validation/test splits, train on everything - test on everything. In fact doing cross validation makes it **wrong**, since you can get 100% without linear separability (as long as you were lucky enough to split data in such a way that each testing subset is linearly separable).

Second of all turn off regularization. "C" in SVM makes it "not hard", hard SVM is equivalent to SVM with C=infinity, so set C=100000 to have at least some decent probability of separating. The same applies to logistic regression in sklearn, it has a hyperparameter C too, set it to 1000000 (basically anything HUGE) and then retrain.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @lejlot. A quick question for you (or maybe a silly one since I'm not expert in this): why is my data is one-dimensional? I have 128 features input. Would it be considered in dimension of my data?

Comment: I corrected the size of the input features, X which was incorrectly reported:
"X is a matrix of (10000, 128) and the output/target/classes are (10000, 10)..."
whould this change your answer or not?

Comment: This only changes the final point, nothing else (which I now removed since after your update it does not apply anymore).

Comment: Thanks for the update. Changed the C parameter to  1000000000 and here what I get for [1] LogisticRegression(C=C) [2] svm.LinearSVC(C=C , loss='hinge') and [3] svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C=C ) respectively: [1] Mean squared error: 0.40 and Variance score: 0.67
[2] Mean squared error: 3.5 and Variance score: 0.34
[3] Mean squared error: 0 and Variance score: 1.00. How do you interpret the results? I doubt if the [3] is reliable!

Comment: This makes no sense. This is classification, there is no "mean squared error" or variance. You should check accuracy.

Comment: get the similar results when I used this command: accuracy_score(y, model.fit(X,y)predict(X))): [1] 0.6749, [2] 0.2725, and [3] 1.0 ----->is it linearly separable (if the procedure makes any sense though!)?

Comment: btw, I believe your comments would be really helpful for me to gain more intuition on other problem of mine. I would really apprecite if you kindly check this post too -> http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/70395/what-is-the-effect-of-hidden-layer-size

Comment: If you get 1.0 accuracy with your model then the data is linearly separable. However again - in the "pairwise sense" since (as stated in the answer) linear separability only makes sense for *binary* classification.

Comment: I see. Thanks @lejlot. I only obtain 1 from `svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C=C )`. `LogisticRegression(C=C)` and `svm.LinearSVC(C=C , loss='hinge')` are both **failing.**

Comment: SVC does one-vs-one decomposition, remaining ones probably one-vs-rest, which as stated before - is much weaker.